# Stuck on creating a Setter method

Tags: java

So at the moment, I've managed to create a getter method with the following code

```
public int getDivisor() {
  return this.divisor;
}
```

That will return 2.

I'm stuck on creating a setter method for my project. The question is: Write a public setter method for divisor, which sets divisor to the value of the argument. It cannot be 0, really am stuck on this question. Can anybody help, please? Much appreciated.

I have now added the following method

```
public void setValue(int number) {
  if (number == 0)
    this.divisor = number;
}
```

for the setter message.

After entering a message `divisor.SetValue();` it comes back the error cannot find symbol - method SetValue(). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, it is just going to set a value, not return something, so you know that it should be `void`. You need an integer as argument, and the name could be "setValue", so `setValue(int number)` can be the signature. You want to set the value of the divisor to this number, so you need `this.divisor = number;`. But you need to make sure that the number is not 0, and that's where the lovely `if(number == 0)` comes handy.

Comment: Always please show your best good faith attempt to solve your problem with your question. Else, how will anyone know what problems you may be having?

Comment: I have edited my post, but still getting a error?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. `SetValue` and `setValue` are two different names.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I feel stupid.... I'm new to Java. Sorry. It doesnt come back with any error but when I send the message divisor.setValue(3); it doesnt change the value, and also when I use divisor.setValue(0); it still changes the value to 0 when it cannot be 0?

Comment: Because you have done the opposite of what you're supposed to do. You have said *"If the value is 0, use it as divisor."* instead of the opposite, when the value is **not** 0.

Answer (score 1):

`setValue()` and `SetValue()` are two different things. Names are case sensitive. That's why compiler couldn't find `setValue()` since you typed `SetValue()`!

Answer (score 0):

First, as pointed out in the comments you're doing the opposite of what you want to be doing. I would suggest that you could throw an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when `number` is 0 like this:

```
public void setValue(int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value 0 is not valid");
    this.divisor = number;
}
```

As for your question about calling your method:

> divisor.SetValue();

As pointed out in the comments, the method signature is case sensitive so **S**etValue will not work. Also, the method requires an integer parameter, you didn't provide any parameters. You should invoke the method like this instead:

`divisor.setValue(123); //Any integer parameter is fine, just an example`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `!=` operator, which means not equals to, on the code

Just do:

```
public void setValue(int number) {

    if (number != 0)
        this.divisor = number;
    }
}
```

This will check if the value given is not equal to 0, and then will proceed to set the divisor to the number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix the method name, a setter should include the variable name which would be like setDivisor()

Second, the condition is wrong, your method will assign the value ONLY IF the value is zero. Therefore it should be: if(number != 0)

Lastly, divisor is a variable, and if you are setting the value inside your class you can either just call the method setDivisor(newDivisor) or this.setDivisor(newDivisor)

Answer (score -1):

A setter method is just a method that sets the value of a variable to that of an argument that is passed through the method typically of the void type since you aren't returning any value

```
public void setValue(int value){
    if(value != 0) this.divisor = value;
}
```

Comment: What about the fact that `value` can't be `0`?

Comment: Apologies I forgot to add in that part.

Comment: do you think to just silently ignore the erroneous input is fine?

Comment: Although the OP probably doesn't understand error handling, it is worth including that in your answer for the purpose of having a proper answer instead of providing a quick solution to the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Gendarme answers from the comment page helped me solved the problem.

```
public void setValue(int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        this.divisor = number;
}
```

Comment: This is still incorrect? Your homework says "It cannot be 0" and what do you do here? ...