# Setter and getter messages

Tags: java

So I've declared a class called Divider and have instance variable private int divisor; with the constructor

```
public Divider()
{

  divisor = 2;

}
```

The question is 
1)Write a public getter method for divisor.
2)Write a public setter method for divisor, which sets divisor to the value of the argument, provided the latter is not 0. If it is 0, the method does nothing. (This is because, as its name suggests, divisor is going to be used to divide, so the argument’s value cannot be zero, and the setter must only set it to non-zero values.)

For the getter message I have

```
public int getValue() {
    return divisor;
```

}

For the setter message I have

```
public void setValue(int number){
   if(number == 0)
   this.divisor = number;

}
```

When I test the code, I send a message to getter and it returns the value 2. But when I test the setter message it sets the value to 0. I don't think that is correct as I cannot use 0 I think. Can anybody help please?

Comment: `if(number != 0)`.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856408/stuck-on-creating-a-setter-method/40856434?noredirect=1#comment68929451_40856434) twice with a different account.

Answer (score 1):

you need to invert the logic, you dont want a dividing by zero errors

```
public void setValue(int number){
   if(number != 0){
       this.divisor = number;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if(number == 0)
```

to

```
if(number != 0)
```

It will not set `divisor` if the argument passed is 0.